# Writing a .txt with URLs in R

Tags: r, url, dataframe, write.table

I have a data frame with one variable `url` and each observation is a url. It looks like this:

```
> df$url

[[1]]
[1] "https://url1"

[[2]]
[1] "https://url2"
```

What I want to do is to output a `.txt` file called `url.txt` where each url is pasted in a straight line separated only by a space (no line breaks, quotation marks etc.). Like this:

```
https://url1 https://url2
```

I have tried `write.table`, however the output look strange. For example every `:` and `/` in the urls are replaced by a `.`. Any ideas on how to achieve this? Thanks :)

**Edit**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(url = list("https://url1", 
  "https://url2")), .Names = "url", row.names = c(NA,
-2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: That data.frame looks funny. Did you somehow store a list in that column instead of a character vector? Does this `df` have only one row or more than one? Is each row supposed to have more than one URL? It would be better to include sample data in a more [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) (like a `dput()` for example).

Comment: Please see the edited question `@MrFlick`.

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit unusual to see a list in a data.frame. In most cases you would expect a character vector. Maybe take another look at how you are building that data.frame. But if we `unlist()`, then I think `cat()` does what you need: `cat(unlist(df$url), file="url.txt")`

Comment: Thanks, I am very new to R so I'm most probably building my data.frame very badly. Although the answer of @fexjoo solved my problem for now, I'll definitely try your suggestion as well. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a bit confused about the structure of your "dataframe". Assuming that your final data is truly a dataframe, this is my solution:

```
library(readr)

# create your example dataset
df <- data.frame(url = c("https://a.b.c/d1-e/2f3g", "https://h.i.j/k4-l/5m5n"))

# Concatenate URLs
string <- paste(df$url, collapse=" ")

# Write file
write_file(string, "url.txt")
```